# Restricting user from downloading via download manager

Tags: php

I have this query for some long time. Not researched more since no requirement at that time.

Now planned to implement and test how it works.

Some or most of you would have come across sites where suppose if there is a file for download named **my_file.rar** and if you try to download through your download manager like **IDM** then it will either pop up some error as **"Failed"** or will download some file namely **"download.php"** instead of that rar file.

The only option to download in that case will be using your Browsers default download option.

I'm confused how they are doing that.

How to proceed for achieving that in PHP file download code.

Say for instance there is a download code like below (This is just a simple code for instance):

```
<?php
$file = "my_file.rar"; //File for Download
echo "<a href='download.php?name=".$file."' download>download</a> ";
?>
```

How to (Some idea would help me proceeding as i am blank now.) restrict the file from downloading using download accelerators in the above case.

**Example:**

Some file sharing sites will disallow free users from using download accelerators and allow the same for premium users

Comment: Dont give the link to users that you dont want to download the file

Comment: @RiggsFolly i doesn't meant that mate. it was just out of curiosity on how they are doing that. As i found some file sharing sites  are restricting the download accelerators for free version and allow the same for premium version